# ReInstalled Ubuntu mounted to same /home partition, How to Access the Old User Home Folders?

Tags: encryption, 17.04, users, home-directory

So my 16.04 recently crashed due to user error.  I decided to update to a newer version of Ubuntu.  I went for 18.04 but ran into the [usersetup error 141](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1761377).  Apparently when mounting to an old home directory this issue can occur.

For reference lets say that I had two accounts set up under home,

- Snow(was a sudo user)
- Angelas(was a normal user)

So I have gone with ubuntu 17.04.  I installed it and set my /home to my old /home partition and installed.  After some hiccups, I now have Ubuntu installed, and can log in, but only to a test user I set up by booting into root.  When I try to log into my main usr ("snow" set up during install) Im reset to the login screen.  I could however

```
su snow
sudo adduser angelas
```

Once again, this account cannot be accessed and then loops me to the login screen.  I can switch user to either of the two above and access their home folders through the terminal.  "angelas" I can see all of the data in the home folder.  "snow" only displays

```
Access-Your-Private-Data.desktop  README.txt
```

It appears that I encrypted my home directory?  I very well might have.  It was a long time ago.

So the question, how do I link my user accounts with their home folders?  How do I set up Ubuntu to unencrypt a home folder and login?

I should be able to guess what my password was if I knew how to start to process.

Comment: fyi: Ubuntu 17.04 was released in 2017 April with a nine month supported life. This ended Jan-2018, so 17.04 is now off-topic on this site, and you should use a supported release of Ubuntu (14.04 LTS, 16.04 LTS, 17.10 or 18.04 LTS).  Only even-numbered year & april are LTS (long-term-support) releases.

Comment: @Thomas I checked out the link, the problem is that I can't even begin the login process, for a encrypted and a non encrypted user.